# does groupby concatenate the columns?

Tags: python, pandas

i have a "1000 rows * 4 columns" DataFrame:

```
a       b    c   d
1       aa   93  4
2       bb   32  3
...
1000    nn   78  2
**[1283 rows x 4 columns]**
```

and I use groupby to group them based on 3 of the columns:

```
df.groupby(['a','b','c']).sum()

print(df)
a       b    c   d
1       aa   93  12
2       bb   32  53
...
1000    nn   78  38
**[1283 rows x 1 columns]**
```

however the result give me a "1000 rows * 1 columns" Dataframe. SO my question is if Groupby concatenate columns as one Column? if yes how can I prevent that. I want to plot my data after grouping it but i can't since it only see one column instead of all 4.

edit: when i call the columns i only get the last column, it means it can't read 'a','b','c' as columns, why is that and how can i markl them as column again.

```
df.columns
Index([u'd'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: No, `groupby ` groups your rows by the columns you've specified. The columns become, for most intents and purposes, like a hierarchical index. It seems to me that if you are getting the same number of rows, after aggregating, each of the of colums you've grouped by is unique.

Comment: i edited the question, when i call the columns it only see col 'd' as a column, so i assume what you said, uniqueness, is not my problem here

Comment: your grouping columns have been placed in the index. they are still in the dataset. `df.groupby(['a','b','c']).sum().reset_index()` will move them out of the index back into normal columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it this way:

```
df.groupby(['a','b','c'], as_index=False).sum()
```

or:

```
df.groupby(['a','b','c']).sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: thank you so much, i appreciate 'Paul's' answer too so i understand how it works